# Chart of opinions on the 13 Middos of Rachamim

Tags: thirteen-attributes

We often recite [**Exodus** 34:6,7](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34.6-7?lang=bi&aliyot=0) in our prayers. These verses contain what are known as the 13 Middos HaRachamim, the thirteen attributes of mercy.

It's actually a dispute how to break up the two verses into thirteen attributes. I recall seeing in a *sefer* somewhere, I thought it was **Toras Chaim** (by Mossad HaRav Kook) but couldn't find it there, a large chart listing many many opinions (I think around 20). Where can I find such a chart? It doesn't have to be the one I remembered, but bonus points if you find that too.

Comment: Some opinions iinm think the 13 are not only in those verses, but also in the verse וסלחת לעוננו ולחטאתינו ונחלתנו.

Comment: IIRC Shadal has such a list.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, and not a chart, but [the Lubavitcher Rebbe has a letter](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15980&pgnum=347) (last section of the page) where he discusses 4 opinions about which word the 13 attributes start from. There are many sources brought there, which may be a good place to start looking for the rest of the information.